# Calculating 2 weeks forward from a day, using a marker day

Tags: sharepoint-designer, javascript, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-addin, jquery

I am trying to code the date of the Thursday which falls two weeks after a given date. It is more complex then just adding 14 days to a given date.

This is because if the first Wednesday after a given date week is the start date, two weeks after it, counting by Thursdays, is more then 14 days where the Thursday of week in which the date was declared is skipped.

I also think that jQuery could be used to shorten the processes.

Just to be clear, I am trying to use this code in a manner where the starting date is a variable which is given. I then calculate the 2 weeks after, skipping the week which the date was declared.

In SharePoint terms i am taking one cell in a table of SharePoint and updating the date in the cell by a measure of 2 weeks where the weeks are counted using Thursdays and the first week during which the date is declared the Thursday is not counted.

I have some code to solve this but I need help integrating it in to SharePoint. Could someone help me integrate the code into SharePoint 2013? The code for the timing (http://jsfiddle.net/bncwcjnf/).

Comment: What table in SharePoint are you referring to?  A list view?  A custom dataview? The table on the NewItem.aspx form?

Comment: I think it is a list view for I can add web parts to the page and it is for a team site.

Comment: If you were to do this globally, would it be based on the column name?  That would mean no one could use that column name anywhere else without having their dates overwritten. I can't say that this sounds like a good idea. But if you really have to do it and you're on 2013, maybe you should look into JSLink. If it were me, I'd probably write a globally reusable workflow that calculates the due date and deploy that on any list for which it applies.

Comment: Therefore, the ID of the column would be the same if any name was the same?

This is a issue that may not mater in the way which i would like to apply the JS. For I just want a JS file which I can apply to a page at anytime. So the name will only exist one time in each list view. Could you guide me on the code?  Would I need to use SPServices?

Comment: I have changed my perimeters and only need to integrate the code in the question in to share point. please guide me on how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

No need for JavaScript,
SharePoint can do all sort of calculations in a Calculated Column Formula
OR Column Default calculations

Do not expect full Excel functionality, but most basic Excel functions work.

The key function you need is `WEEKDAY()` inside some `IF` statements,
also check out the `CHOOSE` function

All SharePoint Functions are documented at:

https://www.365csi.nl/vm365com/365coach/#/Calculated_Column_Functions_List

Comment: ok, but I would like to have this done in a global manner by just attaching a JS file.  so, JS is the way to go.

Comment: Then look into CSR development, and the Cisar tool for it

Comment: the CISR TOOL, ok, very similar to SharePoint Designer which is what i am using. But still both require code... What is the advantage of using the Cisar tool? -- I can do live edits of SharePoint but still does not answer my question.

Comment: I have edited the question to show my idea as how to solve this problem. Please advise.

Comment: Does this help: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/162848/sharepoint-2013-custom-list-calculate-difference-between-today-and-column-value/162881#162881

Answer (score 0):

You would edit the page containing the list view and add a Content Editor Web Part linked to your JS file. In your JS file, you can use JQuery to select the cells that need to be modified, and use a .each() function to modify the date value in every cell.